# Given an instance of a Ruby object, how do I get its metaclass?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass, singleton

Normally, I might get the metaclass for a particular instance of a Ruby object with something like this:

```
class C
  def metaclass
    class << self; self; end
  end
end

# This is this instance's metaclass.
C.new.metaclass => #<Class:#<C:0x01234567>>

# Successive invocations will have different metaclasses,
# since they're different instances.
C.new.metaclass => #<Class:#<C:0x01233...>>
C.new.metaclass => #<Class:#<C:0x01232...>>
C.new.metaclass => #<Class:#<C:0x01231...>>
```

Let's say I just want to know the metaclass of an arbitrary object instance `obj` of an arbitrary class, and I don't want to define a `metaclass` (or similar) method on the class of `obj`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep.

`metaclass = class << obj; self; end`

Comment: Small typo: I think you meant `class << obj`, not `@obj`.

Comment: I knew I was missing the obvious syntax. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 12):

The official name is [`singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class). The way to get it (in Ruby 1.9.2) is simply:

```
obj.singleton_class
```

For older Ruby versions, you can use [`backports`](http://github.com./marcandre/backports):

```
require 'backports/1.9.2/kernel/singleton_class'
obj.singleton_class
# or without using backports:
class << obj; self; end
```